# How can I make a runnable jar on mac from the console?

Tags: java, macos, jar, terminal, runnable

I'm making a game in java, it opens a window, does a few graphics things, and it works from the class files with `java Game`.

I know that using `jar cfm Game.jar src/manifest.txt src/*.class` creates the jar perfectly fine, but it won't run when I double click the jar.

I've seen other code before, and I have even made a runnable jar before, but now I can't find the old one, nor can I find any help (for mac, with the console (NOT ECLISPE)).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's what I have so far:
- Two class files, one with the main method
- The manifest.txt with `Main-Class: Game` (I put an enter as the last line)
- The command to make a jar via the console
- The output jar that has the files in it, but it won't run when double clicking

I think I need to put something on the Game class stating that it implements Runnable, or something of the sort.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does Game class declare "public static main(String[] args)" method?

Comment: I answered my own question, but thanks anyways guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out on my own. No thanks to the internet, mainly oracle... -.-

I put `implements Runnable` right after the Game class, and it worked right away!
Thanks for the help, all those tutorials online that leave that small bit out :/

You don't need to import anything either, just do:

```
public class ClassName implements Runnable {
```

Comment: A runnable jar only needs a `public static void main(String[])` method in the main class defined in the manifest. The main class does not need to implement `Runnable`. Your problem might be that you called the manifest file `manifest.txt` instead of  `manifest.mf`

Comment: no, the compiler automatically converted my manifest from a txt to an mf